# Nginx unknow protocol via ssl

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have issue with configure nginx as reverse proxy via ssl.
This is my configuration:

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    upstream oidc-app {
          least_conn;
          server oidc_1:44338;
          server oidc_2:44338;
    }

    server {
          listen 443 ssl;

          ssl on;
          ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt;
          ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/private/localhost.key;

          server_name  localhost; 
          ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
          ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on; 
          ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH"; 
          ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1; 
          ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m; 

          ssl_session_tickets off;
          resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;

          add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15638400;
          add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
          add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

          error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

          location / {
            proxy_pass https://oidc-app;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme; 
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $http_host;
            proxy_redirect  http:// https://;
          }
    }
}
```

When I open my app in browser I have an error from nginx:

```
*2 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://172.18.0.5:44338/", host: "localhost"
```

Whats more, if I turn on Fiddler and capture https traffic with ignore certificate - everything is fine.
However if I disable Fiddler - an error occured again.

What I'm doing wrong?
If I configure nginx as http via 80 port - everything is fine again.

Comment: Are the services running on port 44338 using `http` rather than `https`?

Comment: Both services are using port 44338 on http. I want to configure reverse proxy to https.

Comment: In that case, you have an error in your configuration. Try: `proxy_pass http://oidc-app;`

Comment: Same response.
Info from nginx: client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 172.18.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:443
Error same as in my question.